# Angular Directive With Binding to Hash of Scope Objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that will allow me to bind to hash of other scope properties.

## HTML

```
<div lookup lookup-model="data.countryId"></div>
<div lookup lookup-model="data.stateId" lookup-params="{countryId: data.countryId}"></div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is every time a value in lookup-params is updated to refresh the lookup with the model of data.stateId.  I'm trying to keep this generic since there is likely a variety of different lookup-params I'll want to have.

Is there a way to do this in Angular?

---

### Update

I certainly didn't provide enough detail.  Clicked submit too soon.  Here is my solution based off feedback from @Olivvv.  The suggestion led me to the `scope.$eval` function.

The goal here was to create a directive that would allow us to use a select with a `$http` get to seed the options within the select.  Some of the `$http` requests will need a parameter since their is a dependency on another value.  For example, a set of states can only be provided when a country value is provided.

The following is the code I pulled together.  I'm sure it can be improved, but it is doing the trick at the moment.  Please note, I'm using Lodash for some utility functions.  You'll also see a scope object "lookupModelObject".  This was purely to meet a design need for styling selects.  It probably can be ignored if you are only interested in the `lookupParams`.

### HTML Snippet

```
<div select-lookup lookup-value="block.data.countryId" lookup-type="countries" lookup-placeholder="Select a Country"></div>
<div select-lookup lookup-value="block.data.stateId" lookup-type="states" lookup-params="{countryId: block.data.countryId}" lookup-placeholder="Select a State"></div>
```

### Directive

The important part to point out is how I'm evaluating the `attrs.lookupParams`.  If the attribute exists I use `scope.$eval` to evaluate the attribute.  You'll later see how I added each parameter to scope and added a watcher in case one of the params changed.  This would allow me to reset the "state" to null if a different country was selected.

```
angular.module("foo").directive('selectLookup', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'common/lookups/partials/selectLookupPartial.html',
        scope: {
            id: "@",
            lookupValue: "=",
            lookupParams: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Initialize the options.
            scope.options = [];

            var optionsLoaded = false;

            var resetLookupModel = function() {
                scope.lookupModelObject = {
                    id: null,
                    text: attrs.lookupPlaceholder
                };
            };

            // Evaluate and obtain the lookup parameters for this lookup.
            var lookupParams = {};
            if (attrs.lookupParams) {
                lookupParams = scope.$eval(attrs.lookupParams);
            }

            var updateLookupModelObject = function(value) {

                // This function is only relevant if the options have been loaded.
                if (optionsLoaded) {
                    if (value === undefined || value === null) {
                        resetLookupModel();
                    }
                    else {
                        var item = _.findWhere(scope.options, {id: value});

                        if (item) {
                            scope.lookupModelObject = item;
                        }
                        else {
                            resetLookupModel();
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

            var fetchValues = _.throttle(function() {

                var deferred = $q.defer(),
                    fetchUrl = "/api/lookup/" + attrs.lookupType,
                    keys = _.keys(lookupParams);

                _.each(keys, function(key, index) {
                    if (index === 0) {
                        fetchUrl += "?";
                    }
                    else {
                        fetchUrl += "&";
                    }

                    fetchUrl += key + "=" + lookupParams[key];
                });

                // Empty the options.
                scope.options.splice(0, scope.options.length);

                $http.get(fetchUrl).then(function(response) {
                    scope.options = response.data;
                    optionsLoaded = true;
                    updateLookupModelObject(scope.lookupValue);
                    deferred.resolve(scope.options);
                });

                return deferred.promise;

            }, 150);

            // Setup the watchers
            // If there are lookup params add them to scope so we can watch them.
            var keys = _.keys(lookupParams);

            _.each(keys, function(key) {
                scope[key] = lookupParams[key];

                // Setup watchers for each param.
                scope.$watch(key, function() {
                    fetchValues();
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('lookupParams', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!_.isEqual(newValue, oldValue)) {
                    lookupParams = newValue;
                    fetchValues().then(resetLookupModel);
                }
            });

            scope.$watch('lookupValue', updateLookupModelObject);

            scope.$watch('lookupModelObject', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!_.isEqual(newValue, oldValue)) {
                    scope.lookupValue = newValue.id;
                }
            });

            fetchValues();
        }
    };
}]);
```

### Template

We had a design constraint that forced us to introduce a "select-placeholder".  Outside of that the select is the "typical" way to setup a select in Angular.

```
<div class="container select-container">
    <div class="select-placeholder">
        <span class="select-placeholder-text">{{ lookupModelObject.text }}</span>
        <select class="select-input" data-ng-model="lookupModelObject" id="{{ id }}" data-ng-options="option as option.text for option in options"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: some more details on the rest of the picture would help.

Comment: Yup just not clear entirely what the goal is... I think you may want something like lookupModel[lookupParams] where lookupParams is bound to a string so you can get a particular property of the model but can't say for sure based on what's here so far.  Can you include a bit about your directive definition or show an example plunkr or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following function in a "utils" service:

```
function  utils    ($parse) {
    this.$params = function(attrs, attrName, allowedParams){
        var out = {},
        parsed = $parse(attrs[attrName])();
        if (typeof parsed === 'object'){
            angular.forEach(parsed, function(val, key){
                if (allowedParams.indexOf(key) !== -1){
                    this[key] = val;
                } else {
                    //do some logging. i.e ('parameter not recognized :', key, ' list of the allowed params:', allowedParams)
                }
            }, out);
        }else{
            out[allowedParams[0]] = attrs[attrName];
        }
        return out;
    };
}
```

use it that way in your template:

```
lookup-params="{countryId: '{{data.countryId}}'}"
```

and in your directive :

```
var lookupParams = utils.$params(attrs, 'lookup-params', ['countryId','anotherParams', 'etcetera']);
```

The first of the allowed params can be passed directly as string instead of an object:

```
lookup-params="{'{{data.countryId}}'}"
```

will work

Comment: This did the trick for me.  The $parse was the key to solving my problem.